# How to get SQl query output to a csv file using unix

Tags: unix

I want to export results of a sql query to a CSV file (comma delimited ) using unix scripting. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Try this (soource: [Export Data From Database to CSV File](http://support.spatialkey.com/export-data-from-database-to-csv-file/))

```
mysql -u user -p pass database -B -e "select * from
\'person\';" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > filename.csv
```